# Suddenly camera becomes so thin and not being scaled

Tags: 3d-view, camera

From **View**, I selected **Camera** .

And my camera became like this. I'm unable to scale this camera.

How to revert the camera back to the normal size ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably changed the resolution settings (or the aspect ratio). Set them back to the size you need for the final output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with the Aspect Ratio here in the Render tab.